# how to reconstruct subsite url in wordpress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress

I have multi-site with folder structure and url example_site.com, and I need URL structure of sub-site to be `example_site.com/locations/state/city`.

I can't find the right hook i even tried `pre_get_posts` hook to change all pages and post but its ugly solution and multi-site will have over 30 sites.

```php
 function filter_url( $url, $path, $blog_id, $scheme ) { 

      if($blog_id = 3){

            $url = str_replace('/city/','/locations/state/city/',$url); 
          }
         return $url; 
    };
```

If i try to echo the result of the function i get what i need but if I returned i get nothing

Answer (score 0):

Make sure DNS is pointing the domain you want to use at the IP address where WP multisite is installed.
Update the Site Address (URL) setting for the subsite you want to change
Run Better Search and Replace on the old subsite domain to the new subsite domain (its default mode is a dry run which does not actually make changes but lets you see how many replacements it will make).